# Using boolean value in QGIS style rule

Tags: qgis, style, select-by-attribute, boolean

I'm trying to make a style based on rules, and I want to use a boolean field I have created for that.

But I do the following:

```
"field" like 'TRUE'
"field" like TRUE
"field" like 1
"field" like '1'
```

and nothing is selected.

How can I select true values in a boolean field then? I'm using QGIS reading from PostGIS database.

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to include the GIS software that you are using, please ?

Comment: I don't think the boolean field supports the *like* operator, try "field" = 1 instead.

Comment: What data source are you using? QGIS doesn't even support creating bool fields in new Shapefiles or Spatialite afaik.

Comment: Sorry: I'm using a postGIS database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using a boolean, you need to use the **`IS`** operator instead of `LIKE`. So your expression should be:

```
"field" is true
```

However, since you want to select the fields which are TRUE, you can also shorthen this and use this expression:

```
"field"
```

This works because in QGIS the fields will be selected, where the used expression returns TRUE. So on a booleanfield it is enough when the content is TRUE and therefore returning TRUE when evaluating it.

Proof:

[image]

Comment: For some reason "is true" wouldn't work for me, but just the "field" option did.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I have found the solution:

```
"field" like 't'
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend, in order to see how QGIS views the values, to use the "all unique" button.

You should get a list of values.

[image]