# Concatenating field names if value is true using QGIS expression

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, concatenation, qgis-expression, boolean

I have multiple boolean fields. I want to create a new string field, that is concatenating the field names of my existing fields when their value is true. I want the names separated by a comma.

I am not sure how to achieve this and which function is the correct one to use. Afaik `concat()` concatenates the values of given fields. I don't really get how `concatenate()` works as the given help is not really explaining what to do to anyone who is not a professional coder.

I imagine a code that checks the field value and if true outputs the name (or preferably any given string), adds a comma and then moves on to check the next field, and so on.

If I did that in Excel it would look like this:

```
IF(VALUEFIELD1="TRUE"; FIELDNAME1;) & "," & IF(VALUEFIELD2="TRUE"; FIELDNAME2;)
```

I hope someone can *'translate'* that into QGIS expressions.

I'm on QGIS 3.34.0 on Windows 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It work almost the same in QGIS.

The & (concatenate) is || (double pipe) and you should use double quote around field name and single quote around text string.
Also the If fonction require the 3rd argument (for when the condition is false)

So your Excel expression become this QGIS expression (using an empty string for FALSE) :

```
 if(  "VALUEFIELD1" = 'TRUE','FIELDNAME1','') || ',' ||  if(  "VALUEFIELD2" = 'TRUE','FIELDNAME2','')
```

Note that the exact syntax will depend on how your boolean field are set up (ie. are they real boolean field or text field with TRUE and FALSE value or numerical field with 0 and 1) in my exemple I use `'TRUE'` as in a text field, for real comparaison boolean see this answer [Using boolean value in QGIS style rule](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148503/using-boolean-value-in-qgis-style-rule)

To deal with non needed comma you need another approach :

- Create an array with value resulting from all If expression
- Filter the array to remove the null value
- Convert the array to string using comma as separator

This should give you Something like that :

```
array_to_string( 
                    array_filter( 
                                    array(if("VALUEFIELD1"='TRUE', 'FIELDNAME1', null), if("VALUEFIELD2"='TRUE', 'FIELDNAME2', null))
                                    , @element IS NOT NULL
                                )
                ,',')
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks a lot! Is there a way to only concat a comma, when there is another value following? Now I get values like ```,,,``` oder ```,,value3,``` (apart from stacking if-clauses)

Comment: @e-shirt see my edited answer for dealing with comma

Comment: Tahnks again. I just tried that but I only get NULL values. Are you sure this approach also works with (true) boolean fields?

Comment: Nevermind, found my own mistake, I still used the concatenator || in the array function. Works now!